# JS, List of dictionary to dictionary of list, based on key

Tags: javascript, node.js, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries, which have some attributes, say a url and some information about the url:

```
[{
    url:"https://example1.com/a"
    something:"ABC"
},{
    url:"https://example1.com/b"
    something:"DEF"
},{
    url:"https://example2.com/c"
    something:"GHI"
},{
    url:"https://example2.com/d"
    something:"JKL"
}]
```

Now I want to split this into a dictionary of lists, grouped based on the url. For the above, my target data structure is something like this:

```
{
    "example1.com" : [{
        url:"https://example1.com/a"
        something:"ABC"
    },{
        url:"https://example1.com/b"
        something:"DEF"
    }],
    "example2.com" : [{
        url:"https://example2.com/c"
        something:"GHI"
    },{
        url:"https://example2.com/d"
        something:"JKL"
    }]
}
```

In python, this might be achieved using the itertools package and perhaps some list comprehension tricks, but I need to do it in javascript/nodejs.

Can someone please steer me in the right direction to do this in javascript?

Cheers.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: How to group object properties by value has been [asked many times before](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+object+group+by+value). Surely you can find an existing answer for your problem? Such broad questions will likely be answered with many different approaches, you really should try something first then ask a specific question about an issue you're having with your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
data.reduce((groups, item) => {
    let host = new URL(item.url).hostname;
    (groups[host] || (groups[host] = [])).push(item);
    return groups;
}, {});
```

One-liner (quite cryptic though)

```js
data.reduce((g, i, _1, _2, h = new URL(i.url).hostname) => ((g[h] || (g[h] =[])).push(i), g), {});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const dataFromQuestion = [{
    url:"https://example1.com/a",
    something:"ABC"
},{
    url:"https://example1.com/b",
    something:"DEF"
},{
    url:"https://example2.com/c",
    something:"GHI"
},{
    url:"https://example2.com/d",
    something:"JKL"
}];

function listOfDictionaryToDictionaryOfList(input, keyMapper) {
  const result = {};
  for (const entry of input) {
    const key = keyMapper(entry);
    if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(result, key)) {
      result[key] = [];
    }
    result[key].push(entry);
  }
  return result;
}

function getHost(data) {
  const url = new URL(data.url);
  return url.host;
}

console.log(listOfDictionaryToDictionaryOfList(dataFromQuestion, getHost));
```

Comment: Yep. Thats it. Can work with that for sure. Cheers.

Comment: `result[key] = (result[key] || []).push(entry);`

Comment: If you initialise *result* as `let result = Object.create(null)` you can dispense with the *hasOwnProperty* test as *result* will only have own properties. And `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(result, key)` seems needlessly verbose, why not `result.hasOwnProperty(key)`?

Comment: @RobG I didn't want to assume the rest of the OP's program was able to handle null-prototype objects. As for Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call, this is to avoid the errors that would occur if there were an item whose key is "hasOwnProperty".

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `reduce` method on the array object.

```
let data = [{
    url:"https://example1.com/a",
    something:"ABC"
},{
    url:"https://example1.com/b",
    something:"DEF"
},{
    url:"https://example2.com/c",
    something:"GHI"
},{
    url:"https://example2.com/d",
    something:"JKL"
}];

let ret = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  let host = cur['url'].substring(8, 20); // hardcoded please use your own 
  if (acc[host])
    acc[host].push(cur);
  else
    acc[host] = [cur];
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(ret);
```